# Java Array reversing task compiling error - IndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to reverse the array; i input length of array than it's all values. After that i'm trying to reverse it doing like that:  a[i] = a[al - i] in the "for construction" - for(int i = o; i < al; i++);
What am i doing wrong there? The full code:

```
package com.company;
        import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int al = s1.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[al];
        for (int i = 0; i < al; i++) {
            a[i] = s1.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < al; i++) {
            a[i] = a[al - i];
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < al; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If an array is of length 2, and if its first index is 0, what is its last index?

Comment: `Arrays` are zero index based, so when `i` is zero you will be calling `a[al]` where `al` is the length of the `Array`, which is not a valid index. Change `a[al - i]` to `a[al - i - 1]`

Comment: Two things: `a[i] = a[al - i];` is **not** a ***swap*** (in addition to the off-by-one bug everyone else has mentioned), and you only **want** to swap the *first half* of the values in the array (or you'll swap them right back).

Comment: Oh my god, i forgot about swapping the second half and using a temp. var. Have to go to sleep. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Description of Your program:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < al; i++) {
        //let al=5, so index of a will be 0..4
        //so for first iteration i=0
        //so a[5-0] i.e: a[5] where 5 is index out of bound
        a[i] = a[al - i];
    }
```

Solution of the problem, but this logic will not reverse your array data:

```
for(int i = 0,j=al-1; i < al; i++,j--) {
            a[i] = a[j];
}
```

For reversing your array data, you have to be used like this:

```
 for (int i = 0, j = al - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
        }
```

So, Whole solution,

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int al = s1.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[al];
        for (int i = 0; i < al; i++) {
            a[i] = s1.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0, j = al - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < al; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```